# Removing Asynchronous Updates on JButtons

Tags: java, swing, asynchronous, jbutton, repaint

I'm doing something very arbitrary, and mainly due to my OCD, but to make a long story short I'd like to remove the asynchronous update on JButtons and invoke repaint() when buttons need to be changed.

Is there any way to do this short of overwriting the overwritten imageUpdate method that JButton implements? I'm working on an assignment and can only turn in a limited number of files.

I appreciate any responses :)

Seeing as it's homework, and I'm in a very large class with some fairly strict regulation against cheating/copy-pasting, I don't feel comfortable with posting my sample code. I'd prefer if any answers were hypothetical! Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when one wants to control component painting, one should override **paintComponent** like this:

```
new javax.swing.JButton(){
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // things you want to do here
    }
};
```

To assume greater control then you may ignore the call to

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

but doing so requires that you

> **must honor the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.**

As [stated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) in the Java API doc.

Answer (score 0):

If it is something you can do with JLabel or JPanel, or one of them with JButton, I would strongly suggest you do so.

JButton is unreliable when it comes to updating status.

If using JButton is absolutely necessary, can you explain what you want to make out of it in greater detail?